# Knowledge Bases: Copyrights or just Copy?

Tags: reference

I was throwing around some ideas on how certain things work like the spell check feature on firefox and suggested terms on a yahoo search (using google as an example is so cliche and not applicable ;).  Microsoft Word, for example, acts sort of like a knowledge system in that it can make certain suggestion about spelling and grammar.

If I decided to go and make a knock off progrom like "Hydro's OpenWriter", I would need a dictionary of words to store in a database to query.  Would I use Webster's Dictionary?  Oxford?  The point is that it is in fact reference material, but still has a copyright.  Does google maps use Natiaonl Geographic's World Atlas? (on Amazon.com for $102.00).   There's time and money that goes into the research, compilation, and redistribution of information.  Yet, its everyday information being used.

Is it indeed free to use in programming applications?  Is that an infringement to the authors?  Is it legal?  Is it ethical?  Are we as programmers responsible for doing original research to build a knowledge base?

Comment: No, clearly you have to respect copyrights placed on those materials, just like you'd expect people to respect the copyrights you place on your source code.

Of course, given the nature of the material, you can sometimes find sources that have placed it into the public domain, or the publishers have provided a very convenient way of licensing that information.

Comment: As for Google Maps: [next time you're there](http://maps.google.com/?ie=UTF8&ll=43.229195,-54.536133&spn=23.415815,39.418945&z=5), note the tiny texts near the bottom of the map frame. They will say something like "Maps (c) 2011 Yoyodyne LLC". Google buys the permission to use those maps; I think that Google can serve the maps to their users for free, but the users aren't allowed to redistribute (as seen in the GMaps EULA). So: yes, information is being used - but the fact that you (the user) have free access to it doesn't mean that it actually comes from a public source.

Answer (score 2):

IMO, red flags go up the moment you start trying to copy anything that is paid for or offered as a product by another entity.  I also think you should probably consult with a lawyer rather than an online Q/A forum for this type of question.

Comment: The point of the topic is gather ideas for building a knowledge-base for an expert system, not to copy another entity's work. I like to use specific examples to make my points. Of course you wouldn't want to just copy. Probably bad labeling on the post on my part.

Comment: I'm sorry if I misunderstood and my answer was not helpful.  It read like you wanted to copy a dictionary.